# My breaker will not turn off the power to the outlets

Tags: electrical

I was going to replace and outlet that broke. I flipped the circuit breaker for the circuit involved. The current was not interrupted by the breaker. I turned off the power to the house, replaced the breaker in the box with a new 15 amp breaker. The breaker worked as is should. One day later, the breaker no longer worked. There are a few breakers that appear to have the same problem. Any ideas about what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure you had the right breaker for that outlet?

Comment: How were you testing that the power was indeed shut off?  Multimeter?  Non-contact tester? Other method?

Comment: Are you thinking that all receptacles in a room are on the same breaker? (The way my house is wired in some rooms receptacles on three walls are on the same breaker, but the receptacle on the fourth is controlled by a different breaker. )

Comment: great questions. I used a southwire non-contact ac voltage detector. There are a large number of outlets and fixtures that are on that particular  circuit that involve 3 rooms. All of the fixtures continue to work when I shut off the breaker. They didn't on the day that I replaced the breaker. that is it worked as it should have. But it no longer works as of today.

Comment: Turn off all the other breakers in the house until you find one that turns the power off then figure out why

Comment: Sounds good. I will try that tomorrow morning. Thanks for the ideas. I may have to turn the power off at the box, and disconnect all the wires and connect them one-by-one and completely map out the house.

Comment: So we have never heard of a circuit that completely bypasses the circuit breaker...breaking power?

Comment: Don't use a non-contact voltage detector for this, they can give false positives. Actually plug something in, such as a 3-light outlet tester.

Comment: My tester seems over sensitive...like my ex wife. I think I am going to splurge for a new and better version (of tester, that is). Meanwhile, I plugged a night light into the socket to test. I pulled the plastic off of the upper half of the socket when I unplugged a printer. That is what started this whole thing.

Comment: What type of panel is it?  Those old FPE panels didn't like to turn power off.

Comment: Yeah, what make and model of panel is it? It sounds like you have a bigger problem than a busted receptacle...

Comment: I agree with @tester101 FPE "stablock" breakers do have problems. I will not repair systems due to the liability. I only replace this specific brand with a new panel or let someone else take the risk.

Comment: Power not turning off = faulty labeling.  New circuit breaker working once = mistake collecting data. I make them all the time.  Ask any scientist.  Best tester = actual appliance.  I own a couple dozen night lights for that purpose.

Comment: Plug-in radio is still my favorite device. Plug in, turn on, crank up the volume, flip breakers until it gets quiet.